# Solspace Importer - Merge two fields in one

Tags: solspace-importer

is it possible to merge two text fields from an XML-Feed into one text field in expressionengine in Solspace's Importer?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You would need to combine those fields in your XML beforehand, i.e. before importing into your custom text field using Importer.